# Save and later restore Docker stack state

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

I'm using docker `swarm deploy -c docker-compose.yml somestack`  to deploy to a docker swarm.  However, I can later scale it with `docker service scale somestack_someservice=5` (or whatever). So now docker-compose.yml no longer reflects the system.  My question is, is there any way to save off the current configuration of the stack, and then later reapply it, similar to how I originally created it (with docker-compose.yml)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no direct way to generate `docker-compose.yml` file, although you can use 
`docker service inspect --pretty <service-name>` command to obtain all configuration in text/json format.

There are some chances we can try to create `docker-compose.yml` from it.

Also, think about lack of this feature as advantage. If you want to make some adjustments, make them in `docker-comose.yml` first and then call `docker stack deploy` to apply it.

Comment: My hope was to be able to identify and re-apply differences between the original compose file and the current state, with the idea being that those changes are wanted.  That said, I guess I could do a "docker service inspect ..." immediately after the stack deploy, as a baseline.  Then later, do another.  From that, I could get a diff, and with a script apply those changes that should be applied. Coupling that with some variable substitution, I should be able to get what I want.